# Python / Pandas - performance - trying to skip a for loop in a full column operation

Tags: python, performance, pandas, for-loop

I have this dataframe called target:

```
target:

          group  estimation_error
170  64.22-1-00          0.061829
72   64.22-1-00          2.242214
121  35.12-3-00         31.960277
99   64.22-1-00          4.819315
19   35.12-3-00          0.850597
```

I want to create a new column called `group_error` which is the median of error of the rows of the same group. It would look like this:

```
          group  estimation_error median_group_error
170  64.22-1-00          0.061829           2.242214
72   64.22-1-00          2.242214           2.242214
121  35.12-3-00         31.960277          16.405437
99   64.22-1-00          4.819315           2.242214
19   35.12-3-00          0.850597          16.405437
```

I was able to do that by doing the following:

```
target['group_median_error']=""
groups=target.groupby('group')

for i in target.index:
    try:
        target['group_median_error'][i]=(groups.get_group(target.group[i])).estimation_error.median()
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

However since that's a large dataframe, it is taking too long. I believe that if I could skip the `for` loop I would have considerable performance gains.

For that intent, I tried to substitute the `for` loop by the following:

```
target['group_median_error']=(groups.get_group(target.group)).estimation_error.median()
```

However it gets me to the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Than I come to the questions:

- Is there a way to perform that same operation without going through the `for` loop?
- Would I have performance gains by skipping that loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do it in a vectorized (without looping) way:

```
In [11]: df['median_group_error'] = \
            df.groupby('group')['estimation_error'].transform('median')

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
          group  estimation_error  median_group_error
170  64.22-1-00          0.061829            2.242214
72   64.22-1-00          2.242214            2.242214
121  35.12-3-00         31.960277           16.405437
99   64.22-1-00          4.819315            2.242214
19   35.12-3-00          0.850597           16.405437
```

Comment: inside the transform shouldn't be 'median' instead of 'mean'?

Comment: @abutremutante, good catch, thank you! I'v e corrected the answer